# Why does this event listener not work?

Tags: javascript

I tried adding an event listener to cars3 id'd paragraph so that when I click the paragraph it should execute the getValue() method but it does not work. I don't understand why. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>

<script>     
function getValue()
   {
        var x=document.getElementById("cars").value;

        document.getElementById("cars2").innerHTML = x.toString();
    }

document.getElementById("cars3").addEventListener("click", getValue());

</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1 id="myHeader" onclick="getValue()">"CLICk HERE !" </h1>

<p id="cars3">afaf</p>

 <select id="cars" name ="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option></select> 
  </select>


<p id="cars2">afaf2</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the brackets:

```
addEventListener("click", getValue());
//--------------------------------^^
```

Making it:

```
addEventListener("click", getValue);
```

*Edited*

Also move script tag below body. Your code is not waiting for the page to get rendered, hence `document.getElementById("cars3")` fails to fetch the element.

```
<body>
  ...
</body>
<script>
function getValue()
  ...
<script>
```

Comment: fantastic thanks for that I did not know the order mattered can you suggest a good source which explains that kind of information ?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, u must take out "()" of the function, and use the event onload of the document, because when your addeventlistener is first called, the html doesnt exists, so cant find cars3 element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>

<script>     
function getValue()
   {
        var x=document.getElementById("cars").value;

        document.getElementById("cars2").innerHTML = x.toString();
    }

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("cars3").addEventListener("click", getValue);
};  


</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1 id="myHeader" onclick="getValue()">"CLICk HERE !" </h1>

<div id="cars3">afaf</div>

 <select id="cars" name ="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option></select> 
  </select>


<p id="cars2">afaf2</p>

</body>

</html>
```